# How do I determine reputable health information soon?

Tags: mental-health

Like many people, I use the internet and various online resources to search for questions that I have about my personal diet, fitness and health regimens/questions.

However, often I run across information that seems correct, but I'm not quite sure of. Often these have what appear to be scientific studies backing them, but when I do a little more investigation, I find other studies directly refuting the claims of the first study.

Add to this there are many sites promoting their own slant on things, such as this website about [health and fashion](http://www.fashionkibatain.com/)

How can I compare differing sources of information to make the best informed choices for my own health?